# Read registry key Value and if found the term, run a bat file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, scripting, powershell-3.0

I wanted to search for "United states" in a registry value and if it exists run a `.bat` file else exit the script.

Reg Key:

```
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Distinguished-Name"
```

Reg Value: *(where  US = United States)*

```
CN=machinename,OU=Computers,OU=US,OU=Sites,DC=brand,DC=com
```

My powershell script:

```
$Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Distinguished-Name" -Recurse |
ForEach-Object {if ($_ -match "United States"){start-process "C:\US_Keyboard_Remove\US_Keyboard_Remove_ActivSetup.bat"}}
```

My batch script:

```
$set "key=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Distinguished-Name"
set "search=United States"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('reg query "%key%" /s^| findstr "%search%"') do reg delete "%key%" /v "%%~a"
```

Please help me to fix the code.

Comment: In your batch script it should be `Set` not `$set`, and your search string should be `US` not `Untied States`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following batch script example should only run 'your specified commands' if the search string was found:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "Key=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine"
Set "Val=Distinguished-Name"
Set "Str=OU=US"
Reg Query "%Key%" /V "%Val%" | Find /I "%Str%" > Nul || GoTo :EOF
Rem your specified commands below here
```

*If you need to run 'your specified commands' if `%Str%` was not found, then change `||` on line `5` to `&&`.*

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt response.